# Группирования с исключением по столбцам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Имеется `df` следующего вида:

```
qw er ty yu io
12 23 34 45 1
12 23 34    2
34 56 42 45 2
34 56 42    1
```

Как сгруппировать, чтобы таблица имела следующий вид:

```
qw er ty yu io
12 23 34    2
34 56 42 45 2
```

Соотвественно, группировка `Max(io)`, но с сохранением значения строки и колонки  `yu`.

Comment: почему вы называете это группировкой - похоже, вы просто выбрали строки с io равным 2 ,

Comment: @splash58 io может содержать различные числовые значения, соответсвенно нужно выполнить группировку с max(io), при этом сохранить столбец и значение строки yu

Comment: а что не сохраняет groupby?

Comment: @splash58 к сожалению, стандартная группировка не дает нужного результата

Comment: не понятно, как все-таки вам нужно группировать. Могут ли у вас для групп с одинаковым , например,`qw` быть максимальные `io`,допустим 2,а я для групп с другим одинаковым `qw` - максимальные io - 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса - вам нужно отфильтровать исходный фрейм таким образом, чтобы получить строки с максимальным значением `io`.

Пример исходного фрейма:

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]:
   qw  er  ty    yu  io
0  12  23  34  45.0   1
1  12  23  34   NaN   2
2  34  56  42  45.0   2
3  34  56  42   NaN   1
```

решение:

```
res = df.query("io == io.max()")
```

результат:

```
In [37]: res
Out[37]:
   qw  er  ty    yu  io
1  12  23  34   NaN   2
2  34  56  42  45.0   2
```

PS группировка подразумевает минимум две операции:

- группирование данных по ключу/ключам
- применение агрегирующих функций к группе строк - в результате чего мы получаем одну строку результата для каждой группы

Поэтому описание в вашем вопросе не совсем правильное. То что вы хотите сделать - это не группировка а фильтрование или выборка по условию.

Comment: благодарю за пояснение, можете подсказать, как будет выглядеть корректно конструкция, если к примеру имея общую таблицу, необходимо примянить группировку к таблице и из групп выбрать строку с максимальным значением по колонке

Comment: @xcplat, советую открыть новый вопрос с __воспроизводимым__ примером данных и результатом, который вы хотите получить